# The relativized element of a relative clause?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

[“Wh” and non-“wh” relative clauses - Page 5](http://www.i.hosei.ac.jp/%7Eevans/courses/grammar/11a_relative_clauses1.html#(5)):

> - “wh” relative clauses (“The bag **which he put there** was stolen.”)
> - “that” relative clauses (“The bag **that he put**  ______  **there** was
>   stolen.”)
> - bare relative clauses (“The bag **he put**  ______  **there** was stolen.”)
>
> In each of these three examples, there’s an anaphoric relation with
> the antecedent “bag”. In the first, it’s from the relative pronoun
> “which”; in the second and third, it’s not from any word that’s said
> or written. But in all three, “he put R there” is understood.
>
> Each of the three has a relativized element. In the first, it’s overt
> (“which”); in the second and third, it’s covert.

It seems that ***that*** doesn't have an anaphoric relation with the antecedent ***bag***. Also, in [page 6](http://www.i.hosei.ac.jp/%7Eevans/courses/grammar/11a_relative_clauses1.html#(6)), in the example of ***that*** relative “a computer [**that** ______ cost too much]” you can see there's a gap indicating the presence of the relativized element, as opposed to the example of ***which*** relative “a computer [**which** cost too much]” in which there is no gap because ***which*** is the relativized element.

Why is ***which*** a relativized element but ***that*** is not? Is it because of the informality of ***that***?

Comment: Incidentally, it's also possible for "that" and gap to be adjacent, as in "This is the part that ___ is worn out", where gap is in immediate subject position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “wh” relative clauses (“The bag which he put there was stolen.”)
>
> “that” relative clauses (“The bag that he put ____ there was
> stolen.”)
>
> bare relative clauses (“The bag he put ____ there was stolen.”)

"That" cannot be R because it's a subordinator, not a relative word (it's the same subordinator that introduces declarative content clauses).

As your examples show, in *that*  and bare relatives the relativised element is covert and represented by the gap notation '____'.

Comment: So when "that" is referred to as a relative pronoun in most of the grammar books out there, it is, however, just a subordinator acting like a relative pronoun?

Comment: @Sam Not quite: relative "that" is indeed a subordinator, but it doesn't act as a relative pronoun because it doesn't have an antecedent in the main clause. Instead, it simply introduces the clause. In _that_ and bare relatives it's the element represented by gap that is anaphoric. The grammar books are wrong!

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't so sure if "that" should be interpreted as a relative pronoun. At least now it's been confirmed.